# Color dia determinado

Tags: javascript, html, css, color

estoy haciendo un calendario con js, html y css, y mi problema es que me gustaría que cuando el dia es un domingo del mes siguiente, pudiera aparecer de un color diferente, por ejemplo un azul. Tengo puesto que me aparezcan los dias del mes siguiente, con un color diferente. Y tengo que los domingos me aparezcan en rojo, de ahi que tengo dos etiquetas diferentes, una para los dias siguientes y una para los domingos. Por lo tanto, no sé cómo darle color a un domingo del mes siguiente. Os dejo mi código:

```js
var actual=new Date();
function mostrarCalendario(year,month)
{
 var now=new Date(year,month-1,1);
 var last=new Date(year,month,0);
 var primerDiaSemana=(now.getDay()==0)?7:now.getDay();
 var ultimoDiaMes=last.getDate();
 var dia=0;
 var resultado="<tr bgcolor='silver'>";
 var diaActual=0;
 console.log(ultimoDiaMes);
 var a=0;
 var b= ++a;
 var last_cell=primerDiaSemana+ultimoDiaMes;
 
 // hacemos un bucle hasta 42, que es el máximo de valores que puede
 // haber... 6 columnas de 7 dias
 for(var i=1;i<=42;i++)
 {
  if(i==primerDiaSemana)
  {
   // determinamos en que dia empieza
   dia=1;
  }
  if(i<primerDiaSemana)
  {
   // celda mes anterior y siguiente
   resultado+="<td class='ayer'>"+(ultimoDiaMes - (primerDiaSemana - i - 1))+"</td>";
  } else if (i>=last_cell) {
  resultado+="<td class='post' style='color: #cccccc'>"+a+++"</td>";}
   else{
   // mostramos el dia
   if(dia==actual.getDate() && month==actual.getMonth()+1 && year==actual.getFullYear())
    resultado+="<td class='hoy'>"+dia+"</td>";
   else
    resultado+="<td>"+dia+"</td>";
   dia++;
  }
  
  if(i%7==0)
  {
   if(dia>ultimoDiaMes)
    break;
   resultado+="<tr></tr>\n";
  }
 }
 resultado+="</tr>";
 
 
 
 var meses=Array("ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE");
 

 
 // Calculamos el siguiente mes y año
 nextMonth=month+1;
 nextYear=year;
 if(month+1>12)
 {
  nextMonth=1;
  nextYear=year+1;
 }
 
 // Calculamos el anterior mes y año
 prevMonth=month-1;
 prevYear=year;
 if(month-1<1)
 {
  prevMonth=12;
  prevYear=year-1;
 }
 if(month+1>12)
 {
 meses[month]= meses[0];
 }
  if(month+1>12)
 {
 meses[month+1]= meses[1];
 }
  if (month >=11 && month <12){
  meses[month]= meses[11];
  meses[month+1]= meses[0];
  }
 if(month-1<1){
 meses[month-2]=meses[11];
 meses[month-3]=meses[10];
 }
  if(month-1 >0 && month-1 <=1){
 meses[month-2]=meses[0];
 meses[month-3]=meses[11];
 }
 //document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+meses[month-1]+" / "+year+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div>";
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML=resultado;
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+year+"</div><div>"+meses[month-1]+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div><div>"+meses[month-3]+"</div><div>"+meses[month+1]+"</div><div>"+meses[month-2]+"</div><div>"+meses[month]+"</div>";
 
}
 
mostrarCalendario(actual.getFullYear(),actual.getMonth()+1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  #calendar {
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:12px;
  }
  #calendar caption {
   text-align:center;
   padding:5px 10px;
   background-color:white;
   
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:medium;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   
  }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(1) {margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(2) { display: inline; margin-top: 5px; width: 20%;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(3) {text-align: left; float: left; color: #cccccc; }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(4) {text-align: right; float: right; color: #cccccc;  }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(5) { float: left; width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 10px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(6) { float: right; width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 10px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(7) { float: left;  width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 14px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(8) { float: right;  width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 14px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(3) a {cursor:pointer;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(4) a {cursor:pointer;}
  #calendar th {
   background-color:white;
   padding: 22px;
   width:40px;
   
  }
  #calendar td {
   text-align:center;
   padding:2px 5px;
   background-color:white;
   font-size:20px;
  }
  #calendar td:nth-child(7) {
   color:red;
  }
  #calendar .hoy {
   background-color:grey;
  }
  #calendar .ayer {
   color: #cccccc;
   }
  #calendar .post {
   color: #cccccc;
   }
  #calendar .post:nth-child(DOMINGO){
  color:blue;}

 </style>
</head>
 
<body>
 <center>
<table id="calendar">
<p>
 <caption></caption>
 <thead>
 
  <tr>
   <th>LUNES</th><th>MARTES</th><th>MIERCOLES</th><th>JUEVES</th><th>VIERNES</th><th>SABADO</th><th>DOMINGO</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Y ya si alguien me pudiera decir cómo poner un hipervínculo a cada uno de los días a otro java, sería la repera. Pero lo que más me interesa es lo del color. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo igual que hiciste con los domingos del mes, puedes chequear i mod 7 asi:

```js
var actual=new Date();
function mostrarCalendario(year,month)
{
 var now=new Date(year,month-1,1);
 var last=new Date(year,month,0);
 var primerDiaSemana=(now.getDay()==0)?7:now.getDay();
 var ultimoDiaMes=last.getDate();
 var dia=0;
 var resultado="<tr bgcolor='silver'>";
 var diaActual=0;
 console.log(ultimoDiaMes);
 var a=0;
 var b= ++a;
 var last_cell=primerDiaSemana+ultimoDiaMes;
 
 // hacemos un bucle hasta 42, que es el máximo de valores que puede
 // haber... 6 columnas de 7 dias
 for(var i=1;i<=42;i++)
 {
  if(i==primerDiaSemana)
  {
   // determinamos en que dia empieza
   dia=1;
  }
  if(i<primerDiaSemana)
  {
   // celda mes anterior y siguiente
   resultado+="<td class='ayer'>"+(ultimoDiaMes - (primerDiaSemana - i - 1))+"</td>";
  } else if (i>=last_cell) {
                  if (i % 7 == 0) {
                  resultado+="<td class='post' style='color: blue'>"+a+++"</td>";
                  } else {
                    resultado+="<td class='post' style='color: #cccccc'>"+a+++"</td>";
                  }
  } else{
   // mostramos el dia
   if(dia==actual.getDate() && month==actual.getMonth()+1 && year==actual.getFullYear())
    resultado+="<td class='hoy'>"+dia+"</td>";
   else
    resultado+="<td>"+dia+"</td>";
   dia++;
  }
  
  if(i%7==0)
  {
   if(dia>ultimoDiaMes)
    break;
   resultado+="<tr></tr>\n";
  }
 }
 resultado+="</tr>";
 
 
 
 var meses=Array("ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE");
 

 
 // Calculamos el siguiente mes y año
 nextMonth=month+1;
 nextYear=year;
 if(month+1>12)
 {
  nextMonth=1;
  nextYear=year+1;
 }
 
 // Calculamos el anterior mes y año
 prevMonth=month-1;
 prevYear=year;
 if(month-1<1)
 {
  prevMonth=12;
  prevYear=year-1;
 }
 if(month+1>12)
 {
 meses[month]= meses[0];
 }
  if(month+1>12)
 {
 meses[month+1]= meses[1];
 }
  if (month >=11 && month <12){
  meses[month]= meses[11];
  meses[month+1]= meses[0];
  }
 if(month-1<1){
 meses[month-2]=meses[11];
 meses[month-3]=meses[10];
 }
  if(month-1 >0 && month-1 <=1){
 meses[month-2]=meses[0];
 meses[month-3]=meses[11];
 }
 //document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+meses[month-1]+" / "+year+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div>";
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML=resultado;
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+year+"</div><div>"+meses[month-1]+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div><div>"+meses[month-3]+"</div><div>"+meses[month+1]+"</div><div>"+meses[month-2]+"</div><div>"+meses[month]+"</div>";
 
}
 
mostrarCalendario(actual.getFullYear(),actual.getMonth()+1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  #calendar {
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:12px;
  }
  #calendar caption {
   text-align:center;
   padding:5px 10px;
   background-color:white;
   
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:medium;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   
  }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(1) {margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(2) { display: inline; margin-top: 5px; width: 20%;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(3) {text-align: left; float: left; color: #cccccc; }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(4) {text-align: right; float: right; color: #cccccc;  }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(5) { float: left; width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 10px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(6) { float: right; width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 10px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(7) { float: left;  width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 14px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(8) { float: right;  width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 14px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(3) a {cursor:pointer;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(4) a {cursor:pointer;}
  #calendar th {
   background-color:white;
   padding: 22px;
   width:40px;
   
  }
  #calendar td {
   text-align:center;
   padding:2px 5px;
   background-color:white;
   font-size:20px;
  }
  #calendar td:nth-child(7) {
   color:red;
  }
  #calendar .hoy {
   background-color:grey;
  }
  #calendar .ayer {
   color: #cccccc;
   }
  #calendar .post {
   color: #cccccc;
   }
  #calendar .post:nth-child(DOMINGO){
  color:blue;}

 </style>
</head>
 
<body>
 <center>
<table id="calendar">
<p>
 <caption></caption>
 <thead>
 
  <tr>
   <th>LUNES</th><th>MARTES</th><th>MIERCOLES</th><th>JUEVES</th><th>VIERNES</th><th>SABADO</th><th>DOMINGO</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eres un héroe, muchas gracias, me sirvió. Por cierto, lo de ponerle hipervínculos a cada uno de los días, me podrías ayudar?

Comment: Solo tienes que encerrar los dias en un `<a href="tu_vinculo"></a>`

Comment: No me deja, se me queda todo en blaco, no se dónde meterlo. Tengo que utilizar esto: <a href="javascript:select_pordias"> pero no se dónde ponerlo. @alanfcm

Comment: Seria asi: `resultado+="<td class='hoy'><a href='select_pordias()'>"+dia+"</a></td>";`

Comment: Vale, me sirvió, pero ahora tengo otro problema. Cuando intento colorear los enlaces, cuando quiero colorear un domingo normal de color rojo, no puedo porque lo tenia puesto como #calendar td:nth-child(7) {
   color:red;
  }, y le da más importancia al <a> que al td. Me podrias ayudar @alanfcm ?

Comment: `#calendar td:nth-child(7) a { color:red; }`

Comment: Vale , ya está solucionado, muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda ^^